# Statistics, Poisson distribution + hypotheses

Tags: statistics

Hey, I find this problem quite difficult to handle,I would be grateful to anyone who could at least lead on the path of solving it.

The random variable X has a Poisson distribution with mean µ. The value of µ is
known to be either 1 or 2 so the following hypotheses are set up.

$H_0$ : µ = 1;   $H_1$ : µ = 2

A random sample $x_1$ , $x_2$ , ..., $x_{10}$ of 10 observations is taken from    the distribution of X and the following critical region is defined.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i\in 1}^{10}x_i \geqslant 15
\end{eqnarray*}

Determine the probability of a Type 1 and Type 2 errors.

Comment: You didn't specify how you choose which hypothesis to accept -- I assume by higher likelihood?

Comment: You also didn't specify a prior. The probability of errors is undetermined unless you make an assumption about the prior. Are you assuming a flat (50/50) prior?

Comment: Type 1 error  is rejecting a true $H_0$ hypothesis and Type 2 error is falsely accepting $H_0$ hypothesis. I'm quite not sure what do you mean by specifying prior.

Comment: The prior is the probability distribution that you assign to the hypotheses prior to taking the sample. For instance, if you know that someone determined the mean $\mu$ by rolling a $6$-sided die and choosing $\mu=1$ if it came up $6$ and $\mu=2$ otherwise, then your prior would be $p(H_0)=1/6$ and $p(H_1)=5/6$. Often one does not have this sort of information about the hypotheses to be tested, and a usual "solution" to this problem is to arbitrarily assume a "flat" prior, in this case $p(H_0)=p(H_1)=1/2$. Without some assumption about the prior, it's meaningless to state error probabilities.

Comment: Also you didn't respond to my first question -- do you choose the hypothesis with the higher likelihood? If not, how do you choose?

Comment: Yes, hypotheses are chosen under higher likelihood.

Comment: From Henry's answer, it seems you may not be interested in the overall probabilities of Type 1 errors and Type 2 errors, but in the conditional probability of a Type 1 error assuming $H_0$ and the conditional probability of a Type 2 error assuming $H_1$ -- those are indeed independent of the prior, so if that's what you're interested in, what I wrote doesn't apply. In that case, you should have indicated in the question that you're looking for a conditional probability.

Comment: @Paul: I just realized I mistook your comments for responses by the OP; they sounded like they were :-) Are you answering what you assume the OP meant?

Comment: @Paul: Interesting, I'm quite sure the author of the question was shown as someone else just a short time ago -- did you just merge two accounts you had? For the future, it will avoid confusion if you use only one of them.

Comment: @joriki, yes, I did change my name, sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 1):

What you are being asked it to find is

1. The probability of being in the critical region if $H_0$ is true
2. The probability of not being in the critical region if $H_1$ is true

The following property of [Poisson distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Properties) will also be useful:

> If $X_i \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_i)$
>   follow a Poisson distribution with
>   parameter $\lambda_i$, and $X_i$ are
>   independent, then 
>   $$Y = \sum_{i=1}^N  X_i \sim  \mathrm{Pois}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\right)$$ 
>   also follows a
>   Poisson distribution whose parameter
>   is the sum of the component
>   parameters.

Perhaps you could try to take this forward and then we could comment.

Comment: Am I right in concluding that you're interpreting "the probability of Type 1 and Type 2 errors" to  mean "the conditional probability of a Type 1 error given $H_0$ and the conditional probability of a Type 2 error given $H_1$"?

Comment: @joriki: I believe that conditional probabilities are part of the standard definitions, though I may be wrong.

Comment: Part of the standard definitions of which terms? There must be some way of talking about the probability of a Type 1 error occurring (i.e. of $H_0$ holding but being rejected) without assuming that $H_0$ holds. (At least in a Bayesian framework there must be.) So the expression "the probability of a Type 1 error" can't simply be defined to mean "the probability of a Type 1 error given $H_0$". The expression that is defined to mean that is "false positive rate": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#False_positive_rate (and analogously for "false negative rate").

Comment: @joriki: I don't think the original question was posed in Bayesian terms.

Answer (score 1):

1) you want to get $P$(rejecting $H_0$ | $H_0$ is true), so when will we reject $H_0$, we will do so if the sum of the 10 observations is bigger than or equal 15. and when does $H_0$ is true, it's true when $\mu = 1$.
let the summation of the observations be $Y$. $\mu$ of $Y = E(10X) = 10E(X)$, since $\mu$ of $X=E(X)=1$, 
$\mu$ of $Y= 10 \times 1 =10$.
since we want to reject it, therefore we want $P(Y \ge 15)=1-P(Y<14)$ where $Y$ is Poisson distributed with $\mu=10$
by using GDC --> `1-poissoncdf(10, 14)= 0.08346`

2) follow the same method :)

Answer (score 0):

1-poissoncdf(10, 14)= 0.08346 is the correct answer

But only one issue, Why is it P(Y≥15)=1−P(Y<14), isn't this a discrete distribution? Why are we using cdf?

Comment: try to explain more so that OP can clearly get solution of their problem